# How to Resolve the Insecure warning in Swapon?

Tags: swap, error-handling

I do

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388    

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/69808/54964
set -e

SWAP_FILE="/media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swap_file_20.7.2016"
SIZE_MB=16000

dd if="/dev/zero" of=${SWAP_FILE} bs="1M" count=${SIZE_MB}
mkswap ${SWAP_FILE}
chmod 0600 ${SWAP_FILE}
sudo swapon -v ${SWAP_FILE}
```

Logs where I am unsure about the part `insecure file owner 1000, 0 (root) suggested`

```
16000+0 records in
16000+0 records out
16777216000 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 121.447 s, 138 MB/s
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 15.6 GiB (16777211904 bytes)
no label, UUID=d3358f33-52d4-4029-8070-213ddf7446b7
[sudo] password for masi: 
swapon /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swap_file_20.7.2016
swapon: /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swap_file_20.7.2016: insecure file owner 1000, 0 (root) suggested.
swapon: /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swap_file_20.7.2016: found swap signature: version 1d, page-size 4, same byte order
swapon: /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swap_file_20.7.2016: pagesize=4096, swapsize=16777216000, devsize=16777216000
```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Related threads: [Accessibility of swap files](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.utilities.util-linux-ng/6742)

Comment: You really don't need to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  Every GNU/Linux system in existence that has bash (i.e. all but some embedded devices that use busybox or tinybox for the shell), has it in `/bin`.

Comment: ^^ that is a rediculous comment ^^, of course you should put a shebang line.. I use an arch linux setup without bash but zsh! so without this line the script would fail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> insecure file owner 1000, 0 (root) suggested.

User 1000 has read and write permission over the swap file.  That means that user 1000 can see or modify anything that goes into swap.  Unless you trust user 1000 and also trust that his account will never be hacked, this is dangerous.

The solution is to make the file owned by root.  If root is ever hacked, your system is lost anyway and root's ownership of this file adds no additional danger.

Thus, make sure the file is owned by root.  On Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, and possibly others (Hat tip: Random832), the group `disk` should be used:

```
sudo chown root:disk /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swapFile
```

On other systems, the group to use may be `root`:

```
sudo chown root:root /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swapFile
```

**Swap is an OS service:**  As Random832 points out in the comments, the swap file is owned by root in just the way that a disk, say `/dev/sda`, is owned by root.  The operating system makes the hard disk, at least the directories that a user owns, available to that user.  In the same way, the operating system allows programs run by a normal user to take advantage of swap when RAM is in short supply.  Root should own the swap file because it is the OS's responsibility to manage swap.

Comment: Try: `sudo chown root:root /media/masi/SamiSwapVirtual/.swapFile`

Comment: @Masi `swapon` creates swap memory that is available for _all_ applications system-wide.  The applications do not need to run as root to use it.

Comment: @Masi Think of it as like who owns your hard drive - /dev/sda is owned by `root:disk` but any user can put files (in directories they own) on the filesystem.

Comment: @Random832 Very good analogy.  I added that to the answer.

Comment: @Random832 You mean it is owned by `root:root`, not by `root:disk`. Command `groups | grep disk` gives blank.

Comment: @Masi This is distribution dependent. There is a disk group (gid 6) and it is assigned ownership of disk devices on both systems that I checked (Ubuntu and Fedora). Also, `groups` shows _your_ groups, not all groups on the system. You want `getent group disk` (or `ls -l /dev/sda`, I suppose)

Comment: @Random832 Command `getent group disk` gives `disk:x:6:`. Which one is correct here: `root:root` or `root:disk`? I am confused. - - Command `ls -l /dev/sda` gives `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jul 20 21:18 /dev/sda`.

Comment: That command just shows that the group exists. When I said `root:disk` it means that the ownership is with user `root` and group `disk`. If you `ls -l /dev/sda` you will (probably) see `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 [DATE] /dev/sda`.

Comment: @Masi _"Which one is correct here: root:root or root:disk?"_  That depends on your distribution.  Use whichever your distribution was designed for.  In olden times, it was always root:root.  As Random832 points out, however, several important modern distributions use root:disk.

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you the problem:

```
insecure file owner 1000
```

Swap files should be owned by root, so after the `chmod` you can do

```
sudo chown 0.0 $SWAP_FILE
```

Comment: I get `Text file busy` in trying to execute the script which creates the swapFile after doing the change with `chown`.  See the thread http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388. You cannot run Matlab as root. I am not sure if this solution is possilble at all in the target.

Comment: @Masi I think you already activated the swapfile (that's why it is busy). Check with `swapon -s`. Use `swapoff` on your swapfile if you want to re-run the script.