# Which first level directories in Linux should be owned by user?

Tags: directory, root, chown, ownership

Today, I have accidentally noticed that the following directories of the `/` are **owned by `user`**, rather than `root`:

- `/home`
- `/lost+found`
- `/media`
- `/mnt`
- `/opt`
- `/snap`
- `/srv`
- `/swapfile`
- `/var`

I have no idea how that could happen. It seems only logical that some of them with the obvious exception of `/home` should be owned by root. If so, which ones?

On the other hand, the `Lubuntu 20.04 x64` system and installed software run both normally.

I do not face any troubles at the moment.

Should I follow the *"If it is not broken, don't fix it"* approach?

Comment: `/home` is not an obvious exception. What happens when you create another user ? `/home` should be owned by root, `/home/myUser` should be owned by that user. On my Linux (Mint 19.3), everything belongs to root.

Comment: Why do you think `/home` shouldn't be owned by root? `/home` isn't _your_ home directory, it contains home directories

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Yes, you are right, my mistake.

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should all be owned by root.

> On the other hand, the system (Lubuntu 20.04 x64) runs normally. So does installed software, I do not face any troubles at the moment. Can it be the case when this saying «If it is not broken, don't fix it» is to be remembered?

No. I would consider your system broken (not horrible broken but broken). It just doesn't hurt you yet. The directories are usually owned by root. So for any other user it makes no big difference whether it is owned by root or someone else and root is root and just access it regardless of the owner or permissions.

Apart from the security aspect some software might to refuse to run if the owner is not as expected. E.g. I can imagine a swapfile owned by user can become problematic. It is at least a [warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297149/how-to-resolve-the-insecure-warning-in-swapon).